# Running du on timeshift folders give different results

Tags: linux, backup, snapshot, du

My goal is to find which files/folders take the most space in a `snapshot` from the backup tool `timeshift` but, when using `du` it yields different results:

```
# du -hs *
18G     2018-09-21_16-14-57
910M    2018-10-06_07-04-27
```

Second folder only

```
# du -hs 2018-10-06_07-04-27
18G     2018-10-06_07-04-27
```

The result that I want is the 910M one, which I then want to drill into to find which folders/files are taking the most space within that.
Why is `du` giving different results?? How do I get to drill the 910M result?

I know that the second folder is full of hard links (that's how the tool works) but `du` should not report different sizes since the `*` simply expands to the actual folder names in `bash`, should it?

**Update:** I just tried `# du -hd 2 *` which seems a step in the right direction but it's not a reasonable solution when there are 20 or more snapshot folders and I only want to drill into one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `du` should not report different sizes since the `*` simply expands to the actual folder names in Bash, should it?

It should, it's still just one `du` process and it's trying to be smart.

Rationale: If `du *` wasn't smart, it would be difficult to make it smart. The other way around is easy, it's quite simple to make the smart `du` "dumb". If you want completely independent results then just run separate `du`-s for the two directories.

Few general examples of invoking separate `du`-s:

```
for d in *; do du -hs "$d"; done
find . -exec du -hs {} \;
```

They do differ in details. The `find`-based one can be customized (e.g. start with `find . -type d …`).

Also check `--apparent-size` option if your `du` supports it.

It's a different issue whether or not making `du` "dumb" will be useful for you, since you want "to find which files/folders take the most space". [The other answer](https://superuser.com/a/1364373/432690) is right:

> If the files in a folder correspond to inodes with multiples links, erasing them in that folder won't change anything.

The smart behavior of `du` seems to fit your needs a lot more than the (forced) "dumb" one. My advice is to take an advantage of it and the fact `du` processes its arguments in the given sequence. This means the reported size of *the very last object* is what you will get if you remove this object and only this object (unless it contains hardlinks to yet another location where this particular `du` didn't peek).

In your example the expanded command was apparently:

```
du -hs 2018-09-21_16-14-57 2018-10-06_07-04-27
```

The result says you'll get `910M` if you remove just `2018-10-06_07-04-27`. Now try another sequence:

```
du -hs 2018-10-06_07-04-27 2018-09-21_16-14-57
```

The last line of the output will tell you how much space you will get if you remove `2018-09-21_16-14-57` only.

If I were you I would also investigate `ncdu` (interactive tool) and its behavior.

Answer (score 1):

Obviously `du` ignores inodes it already accounted for in other directories it visited. For instance with your example:

```
du -hs 2018-09-21_16-14-57 2018-10-06_07-04-27
du -hs 2018-10-06_07-04-27 2018-09-21_16-14-57
```

will give different results.

But in your case, it shouldn't make much difference. If the files in a folder correspond to inodes with multiples links, erasing them in that folder won't change anything. IMHO you should focus on inodes instead of directories (which means not use the `-s` parameter in `du`).